# operator is, the list

Tags: prolog

I use this function:

```
f(V):-V is [1,2,3,4,5].
```

But I get an error:

```
ERROR: '.'/2: Type error: `[]' expected, found `[2,3,4,5]' ("x" must hold one character)
```

What needs to be fixed?

Comment: Depends. What did you expect the code to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`is/2` infix operator is used to evaluate arithmetic expressions.

It seems that you want to unify variable V with a term which is not an arithmetic expression (in this case a list), so you should use the equal operator (`=`).

```
f(V):- V = [1,2,3,4,5].
```

or alternatively unify directly in the head of the procedure:

```
f([1,2,3,4,5]).
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code indicate the need that f/1 enumerates among a small set of numbers. If this is true, you should write instead

```
f(V) :- member(V, [1,2,3,4,5]).
```

then when calling `f(X)` X will bind (on backtracking) the values listed.